# Always run proguard-maven-plugin before install phase

Tags: maven, proguard, maven-plugin

What I am trying to do, is to obfuscate a certain packages in a multi module application, **before** it gets installed to my local repository, so that the final package will be an EAR file which contains obfuscated jars.

I tried to obfuscate the jars during EAR building process without success. Now i want to build the EAR with obfuscated jars instead ob obfuscating then during the build.

So I've got the following plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
      <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.11</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
          <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
          <version>${version.proguard}</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>process-classes</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>proguard</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        ...
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So there are two problems for me:

1. Progruard always runs **after** the install phase, so that the EAR build always gets the not obfuscated jars
2. I always have to add proguard:proguard to the maven command, which of course fails in a multi module project where some modules don't have to be obfuscated

So my questions:

1. How can I obfuscate the package before it gets installed?
2. How can I make plugins like this one run on default without adding `<phase>:<goal>` to the maven call?

Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for the proguard plugin to work, JAR files are needed. Perhaps you can achieve this by attaching the proguard plugin's `proguard` goal to the `package` phase (and not `process-classes` phase) of the default Maven build life cycle as proposed [here by Alexey Shmalko](http://www.alexeyshmalko.com/2014/proguard-real-world-example/). It's not clear to me if you are using the `maven-shade-plugin`, but if you are, then place the proguard plugin configuration your in pom.xml *after* that of `maven-shade-plugin` (this is because both these plugin attach to the same phase: `package`).

My expectation is that since `package` phase is achieved before `install` phase, it should give you the effect you are looking for.

Comment: I already know this link :D Moving the plugin to `package` phase makes no difference. I am not using the `maven-shade-plugin` because I just want to obfuscate the package and not its dependencies. For this i added `<injar>classes</injar>`